# SVG <clippath> change each character color in a <text> tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having a problem
text with background image, and each text will fill with rgb(transparent) color. and it will be browser support.

so I am using clippath.now I want to change each character color in a text tag. how is it possible?? anyone help me out ?

[here is my fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/o8hbjnpw/)

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="1200" height="400" viewBox="0 0 1200 400"> 
    <!-- add title for accessibility -->
    <title>Adding Background to Text using SVG clipPath</title> 
    <defs>  
        <clippath id="my-path">
            <text x="50" y="300" font-size="200" >hello</text>
        </clippath>
    </defs>
    <image xlink:href="http://rusafy.net/test/omega/images/ls-s3-0.jpg" clip-path="url(#test)" width="100%" height="100%" preserveAspectRatio="none" />
</svg>
```

```css
image {
    clip-path: url(#my-path);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "changing each text color" ? If you mean "each character", maybe you just have to put each character in a `text` tag.

Comment: Maybe you should put each character in a different `<text>` tag, with different `color` value.